# Influencing spelling suggestions in the Google search appliance

Tags: gsa

We have a problem with spelling suggestions from our Google search appliance. For a particular search term, it offers a completely incorrect spelling suggestion, which, apart from being unhelpful, is at odds with the otherwise carefully managed tone of our web site. The word is present in some documents, but is completely unrelated to the search term.

From what I have read so far, spelling suggestions are not something that you can explicitly manage, but are gathered from within the corpus the GSA is indexing. We can see that it's not a default result, because the index of our development systems doesn't offer this suggestion.

The [Google documentation](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/current/gsa_doc_set/admin_searchexp/ce_understanding.html#1027068) says: "You cannot edit the search appliance's spelling dictionary." It then goes on to list some other options for improving searches, none of which seems to include being able to remove or prevent such spurious suggestions.

So what are the options? Can we directly influence the spelling suggestions for a specific word or words in some other way? Can we get the machine-learning system to forget what it's learned so far? Are there other possible solutions?

Comment: What does Google Support say?

Comment: Is that your downvote EEAA? If so, do you mind explaining?

Comment: Nope, but if it were, it would not matter. Downvotes without comment can be assumed to be made due to one of the reasons on the dv hover text.

Comment: OK - apologies for the false-association. Just your comment arrived around the same time.

Comment: My question stands, though. What did vendor support day? Vendor support, especially for niche technologies like this, should always be your first contact.

Comment: ....and what about actual humans in the Google Support team? There may be an un-documented way to do this.

Comment: Spelling or query suggestions? You can have a suggestions black list, see: https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/admin_console_help/serve_suggestions.html

Comment: We opened a ticket some time ago for this, and the answer was that it's a "feature request". As the documentation still doesn't mention any solution, asking for suggestions here seems reasonable.

Comment: Brian - I'm talking specifically about spelling suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Spelling suggestions are based on key-word search popularity. The only way to influence it (as a non-google 3rd aprty) is significantly contribute to the increase in popularity of the alternate term you want.

That, ignoring the various implementations of the future we-dictate-the-truth policy.